# C# Disable click/doubleClick or any WindowsMessage

Tags: c#, windows-messages

My goal is to disable all `DoubleClick()` events in my application. Just simply unsubscribing from those events is not possbile, because those are external custom controls. So I am aiming for disabling either the `DoubleClick()` for those controls or my whole application, it doesn't really matter.

What I am trying to do is to intervene once the window gets a WindowsMessage `WM` and the ID number `Message.Msg` is the code of e.g. a `Button.Click()` event.

```
private const int WM_COMMAND = // ???

if (m.Msg == WM_COMMAND)
    ...
```

But no matter which WindowsMessage notification code I use, I don't get the correct one which gets fired once a control gets clicked. But I was abel to intervene on a `DoubeClick()` on the `Form`.

```
private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3;
private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
    {
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        return;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

This works totally fine and disabels a `DoubleClick` on the *client area* and *non client area* of the `Form`. But in which *area* do I locate when I am hovering a control? Because those WindowsMessages referred to either the *client area* and *non client area* dont' get fired when I am on a control.

---

> Sent when the user clicks a button.
>   The parent window of the button receives this notification code through the WM_COMMAND message.

[MSDN doc about a button click notifaction message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761825(v=vs.85).aspx)

The `WM_COMMAND` message has this notfication code:

```
private const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
```

So when I try to react to this message being sent I can't, because this message doesn't get fired.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_COMMAND)
        MessageBox.Show("foo"); // nothing happens

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

What do I miss or missunderstand about this WindowsMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one posted an answer yet and I found a well working solution here is my attempt to disable all `DoubleClick()`s or just for one/a few desired `Control`/s.

The problem is that `WndProc()` doesn't filter or respond to *all* `WM`s that are being sent. Therefore the `WM` for a default `doubleClick` on the *non client area* `0x0203` can't get detected. So I went deeper to already filter the `WM`s before they reach `WndProc()`. One way is to use a `MessageFilter` that is being assigned to my `Application`.

```
private MessageFilter msgFilter = new MessageFilter();

Application.AddMessageFilter(msgFilter);
```

The method Param is an object of my own class `MessageFilter`, which needs to implement the `IMessageFilter` Interface in order to use it's `PreFilterMessage()`. This method gets invoked for *each* single `WM` that gets send to your application.

```
class MessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0203)
        {
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

So basically once there is a `WM` with the desired `Message.Msg` ID, I set the `Result` to `zero` so the `DoubleClick()` is completely disabled for the whole application.

---

Later on it turned out it would be better to disable the `DoubleClick()` only from one `Control`. Since every `Control` in Windows has a unique `Handle HWnd`, which is part of the `Message`, I can use it to scan if the certain `Message` aims to my specific single `Control`.

When you create your `Control` either subscribe in the `.Designer.cs` to the event:

```
this.yourControl.HandleCreated += new System.EventHandler(this.yourControl_HandleCreated);
```

Or if it's a custom `Control` subscribe to the event after it's creation. In the event you assign the value of the created `Handle` to any instance your `MessageFilter` has access to, like a `Property` in this class.

```
private void yourControl_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    msgFilter.OwnHandle = yourControl.Handle;
}
```

After that simply add a second condition to the `if` statement:

```
if (m.Msg == 0x0203 && OwnHandle == m.HWnd)
    ...
```